# Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Tags: javascript

Реализуйте функцию getPromise(delay, message), которая принимает целое число задержки (от 0 до 2000) и строковое сообщение и возвращает Promise, которое ожидает указанное количество времени (используя аргумент задержки) и разрешается с сообщением.

```
    function getPromise(delay, message) {

    return new Promise(function (resolves, reject) {
        
        setTimeout(function (delay) {
            
            const message = 'hello'
            resolve(message)
        }, 2000);
    })

}
let promise = getPromise();

promise.then((message) => {
    console.log(message);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все делаете правильно, за исключением наименования аргументов промиса. Задаёте `resolveS`, вызываете `resolve`

```js
function getPromise(delay, message) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { //здесь было resolveS
    setTimeout(function (delay) {
      const message = "hello";
      resolve(message);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
let promise = getPromise();

promise.then((message) => {
  console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: Еще у таймера задано фиксированное время, что не выполняет задачу.

Comment: Как таймаут влияет на выполнение задачи, если он просто добавляет задержку?

Comment: "возвращает Promise, которое ожидает указанное количество времени и разрешается с сообщением."